# Loop over JSON and create files with key as filename and value as file content

Tags: bash, jq

I have a sample JSON like

```
  "request_id": "016-ae81e5737add",
  "renewable": false,
  "data": {
      "client_decrypted.key": "-----BEGIN KEY-----sdjijhgisdTRjkRD05\n-----END KEY-----",
      "passphrase": "password"
    }
```

In my bash script, I am reading the JSON specifically the contents of `data` key. I would like to create files with the filename as `key` (e.g: files like `client_decrypted.key` & `passphrase`) with the contents of the files as the `value` of the corresponding key.

I was able to use jq to read the key & value pair

```
for pair in $( jq -r ".data | to_entries|map(\"\(.key)=\(.value|tostring)\")|.[]"); do
    echo $${pair} # OUTPUT=passphrase=password
done
```

I guess I can use IFS to split each pair on `=`. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have edited my question. The full JSON snippet has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One safe way would be to emit the JSON records with a NULL byte padding and then later read it back in a shell loop, delimiting on that byte

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' key && IFS= read -r -d '' value; do
    printf '%s\n' "$value" > "$key"
done < <(jq -j '.data | to_entries[] | (.key, "\u0000", .value, "\u0000")' json)
```

Since the NULL byte can't be part of a "valid" byte in any of the input records, it is used as the delimit character. The `jq` expression

```
(.key, "\u0000", .value, "\u0000")
```

appends the NULL byte between the key and the value field, which is read with a while loop , two reads at a time to store the key name and the value fields in the respective variables.

Note that `<(..)` is a bash/ksh93/zsh process substitution technique, which is not POSIX compliant and might not work in pure bourne shells.

Comment: “safe”?  Safety here would presumably mean checking or sanitizing the key.

Comment: I control the source of the JSON values. So I don't think I need to check for null values, is that is what you mean by sanitizing the key?